# Error when building with MinGW on Ubtunu

Tags: makefile, mingw, fatal-error

I am using Ubuntu  and I want to compile my project to Linux and Windows. With a bit of googling, I found MinGW. I set up my makefile to build my project for both Operating Systems, with the exact same parameters for Windows and Linux. The build for Linux works, but when I run the Windows make, I get this error:

```
src/gl3w/glcorearb.h:616:10: fatal error: KHR/khrplatform.h: No such file or directory
 #include <KHR/khrplatform.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I'm not sure how libraries are used and shared between GCC and MinGW, but I assume that MinGW is just missing the required libraries.

How can I install the required libraries? (if my hypothesis was correct)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL sources depend on the Khronos header. When you download and compile OpenGL yourself you will download khrplatform.h file from official site https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/api/KHR/khrplatform.h.

As OpenGL owner write (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php):

> The OpenGL headers all depend on the shared  header
>   from the EGL Registry . This is a new dependency, introduced in
>   OpenGL-Registry pull request 183 for increased compatibility between
>   OpenGL and OpenGL ES headers.

So

1. Download khrplatform.h
2. Create dir 'KHR' in you */usr/include*.

   ```
   cd /usr/include
   sudo mkdir KHR
   ```
3. Copy *khrplatform.h* file in /usr/include